# How to personalize table format

Tags: tables

I have a small question. I am compiling my tables in LaTeX. I wrote the following code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering\footnotesize{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Baseline model \label{table3}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
\hline\hline
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{First Model}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Second Model}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}\\

\hline

Regressor1 &.010***& .009***& & .010***& & .009***\\
           & (.001)& (.001) & & (.001) & & (.001)    \\
Regressor2 &       &        & .016***&   & .016***&\\
           &       &        &  (.002)&   & (.002) & \\
\hline
Observations & 107048 & 107048 & 107048 & 107048 & 107048 & 107048  \\
R$^2$        & .072   & .074   & .080   & .080   & .080   & .080     \\
F-test       & 257.792 & 188.037 & 188.037 & 188.037 & 188.037 & 188.037 \\
log(likelihood) & -3.14e+04 & -3.13e+04 & -6.97e+04 & -6.96e+04 & -6.96e+04&   -6.96e+04   \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize * \(p<0.10\), ** \(p<0.05\), *** \(p<0.01\)}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

The table looks as I need. However, I would like to include a horizontal line under First Model and Second Model headings.
Could anyone suggest how to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Dario

Comment: note size commands do not take an argument so the `{` (and matching `}`) should not  be used here: `\footnotesize{` do you just want `\hline` after the `\\ ` that ends the row?

Comment: Dear David, I am not sure I understood your question. Anyway, I try to explain better. I do not want an \hline after First Model and Second Model. I would like to have only a line under First Model and another under Second model. I hope I clarified my point.

Comment: The only way this makes sense is if the line stretches across columns 2 and 3 (first line) and columns 4-7 (second line). Is that what you want? You can use `\cline` but the results will be a continuous line across columns 2-7. Your table would benefit from the advice given in the **booktabs** documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remember to give complete, compilable code when posting examples. I've invented a page width to make the table fit as it is too wide for the default page layout. A complete example would avoid these kinds of issues and make it a lot easier for people to help you.

---

Writing

```
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First Model}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Second Model}\\\cline{2-3}\cline{4-7}
```

will add lines under the row spanning columns 2-3 and 4-7 respectively. However, the result is extremely unclear:

[image: orig table of results with added clines]

The table also seems too squashed in general and the use of double lines is not ideal. It would better to space things out a little, clarify the relationships between the headers and the columns and replace double lines with heavier rules, as happens in professionally typeset tables.

Here's a way of achieving these goals using **booktabs** and **threeparttable** (*via* **threeparttablex**). This improves the layout, clarifies the relation between the headings and columns and improves the layout of the notes and spacing around the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[scale=.75]{geometry}
\newcommand*\sym[1]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering\footnotesize
  \renewcommand*\sym[1]{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Baseline model \label{tab:description}}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
      \toprule
      &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First Model}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Second Model}\\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-7}
      &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&(2)&(3)&(4)&(5)&(6)\\
      \midrule
      Regressor1 &.010\tnote{***}& .009\tnote{***}& & .010\tnote{***}& & .009\tnote{***}\\
      & (.001)& (.001) & & (.001) & & (.001)    \\
      Regressor2 &       &        & .016\tnote{***}&   & .016\tnote{***}&\\
      &       &        &  (.002)&   & (.002) & \\
      \cmidrule(lr){1-7}
      Observations & 107048 & 107048 & 107048 & 107048 & 107048 & 107048  \\
      R$^2$        & .072   & .074   & .080   & .080   & .080   & .080     \\
      F-test       & 257.792 & 188.037 & 188.037 & 188.037 & 188.037 & 188.037 \\
      log(likelihood) & -3.14e+04 & -3.13e+04 & -6.97e+04 & -6.96e+04 & -6.96e+04&   -6.96e+04   \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item[*]\(p<0.10\),
      \item[**]\(p<0.05\),
      \item[***]\(p<0.01\)\par
      \item[]Standard errors in parentheses
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: clarified table of results]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your ansers guys. In particular, the last one is exactly what I wanted. Next time I will be sure to post the entire code. I apologize.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.